# Transferring Music in iOS via Bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, mpmediaitemcollection

I have set it up to where music can be sent back and forth between iOS devices, but whenever the music is sent, the receiving phone gets this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'MPMediaItemCollectionInitException', reason: 'items array must not be empty'
>   *** First throw call stack:

This is the method where I get the error:

```
-(void)didReceiveDataWithNotification: (NSNotification *)notification{
    MCPeerID *peerID = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"peerID"];
    NSString *peerDisplayName = peerID.displayName;
    NSData *receivedData = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"data"];
    //NSLog([[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"data"]);
    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:receivedData];
    NSString *datatype = [dict objectForKey:@"datatype"];
    NSLog(@"hi");
    if([datatype isEqualToString:@"musiclist"]){
        count++;
        MPMediaItemCollection *collectionFromPeer = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:[(MPMediaItemCollection*)[dict objectForKey:@"data"] items]];
        [_listOfMusic addObjectsFromArray:[collectionFromPeer items]];
        if(count == [[_appDelegate.mcManager.session connectedPeers] count] + 1){
            for(int i=0;i<[_listOfMusic count];i++){
                int r1 = arc4random() % [_listOfMusic count];
                int r2 = arc4random() % [_listOfMusic count];
                [_listOfMusic exchangeObjectAtIndex:r1 withObjectAtIndex:r2];
            }
            MPMediaItemCollection *coll = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc]initWithItems:_listOfMusic];
            [_musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:coll];
            NSLog(@"hi3");
            [_musicPlayer play];
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong with it or what is causing this error?

Comment: Which of the two calls to `initWithItems:` is failing? What debugging have you done to ensure that `dict` has the data your code assumes?

Comment: @rmaddy It fails and throws that error when assigning dict

Comment: On the other side of the code, when I am sending the data, I have it print out the data it sends right before it sends, and it is the correct data before it is sent

Answer (score 0):

Check two points which may cause the problem:
One: where is `_listOfMusic` init?
Two: how do you know `[dict objectForKey:@"data"]` is a array and has items?

Comment: _listOfMusic is initialized in the viewDidLoad method of the ViewController

Comment: and [dict objectForKey:@"data"] is a specific array that I created when I actually send the data via the MultipeerConnectivity framework, so it is definitely an array, and it has items right before it sends as well